# Programmatically instanciating objects thats classes have Spring life-cycle annotations

Tags: java, spring, unit-testing

I am testing a set of classes that will, ultimately, be used to create beans within Spring contexts. I am using JUnit for testing. I want to ensure that when instances of these classes are instantiated **programmatically** within a test that the life-cycle methods and the @Required setters are correctly called. I know I can do this via a plain-old-java-proxy but am wondering if there exists specific tools within Spring (or elsewhere) that will help me.

I am looking to write something like

```
X x = ???.newBeanInstance(X.class); 
x.setFoo(foo); 
x.setBar(bar);
x.$postConstruct(); 
... 
x.$preDestroy();
x = null;
```

The other, less desirable, option is to just create the context's XML and use it to initialize the instances.

Answer (score 2):

If you bring-up the whole context, you can use the `spring-test` package and its `@ContextConfiguration`.

If you want to handle things manually, you are on your own (almost). If you have field injection, you can use `ReflectionTestUtils` to set dependencies. But apart from that you:

- instantiate the object with `new X()`
- call setters
- call the initializer method (you should know which one it is)
- call the destruction method in the end